# How long should I wait before planting water propagated english-ivy?

Tags: propagation, english-ivy

So I'm finally succeeding rooting ivy on water, I don't want to ruin it when placing them on the soil. Anyone knows how long should I wait? I know that for pothos I should wait until the roots are around 2 inches long.

Comment: Up pot into a small pot no matter what.  Water roots are NOT soil roots.  Hedera is like a weed, honest.  It is tough.  In the states, Hedera IS a weed, it is that tough and reliable.  In a large pot there is the chance you could rot the roots.  A large pot with a lot of soil and a little plant with iffy roots to suck the water up could easily cause root rot.  When the plant fills that pot with roots (you'll see the roots coming out of the bottom), THEN up pot to a slightly larger pot, 1 or 2 inches wider in diameter.  If you are keeping in a pot, keep up potting until 3 gallon pot.

Comment: Is this Pothos or Hedera? Same advice but are you wanting to plant out of doors?  Big caveat here; you have to acclimate that plant after it has gone through 2 repottings.  About a 4" pot, roots coming out of the bottom or turn upside down and shake it out to LOOK at the roots. Then you start the acclimation; outside in the sun for 10 minutes for 3 days, then 20 minutes for 3 days, then 40 minutes for 3 days and then your plant should be acclimated.  I'd probably do 60 minutes for 3 days and THEN plant out of doors in the sun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be fine if the roots are an inch or more long - Hedera is a tough plant, but plant up into a small pot  with new potting soil to give it time to develop properly before planting  in the garden (if that's your intention). If tou want to keep it in a pot, pot up into something larger as it grows bigger and has formed a good root ball.